# Tool to edit CSS color-scheme

Tags: css, editing, color-scheme

Is there a tool that allows me to load a CSS file, and apply filters to the color scheme? Like rotating hue of all color, change global lightness/darkness, saturation... Something like a photoshop of the CSS world! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

http://cssprism.com/

Comment: does not exist anymore

Answer (score 2):

have a look at sass http://sass-lang.com/ recent check-ins on github allow for pretty extensive manipulation of colors

See: http://nex-3.com/posts/89-powerful-color-manipulation-with-sass

Comment: There must be a better way... and anyway this seems to be something you use to construct your CSS in a way that it is programable, so it has to be made for that. What I want is to get a CSS, .. any CSS, and edit the color-scheme, and then press save, and finished! The new CSS is there, with all colors changed!

Comment: Thats easy, it ships with css2sass which goes to sass. Sass is by far the most advanced css DSL out there, if you want something different you would be looking at something experimental that has not had much real world use. I use sass for everything if I want to change all the colors in my style sheet I edit a single value in a single file, press reload on the browser and bam its all changed. Its about to ship with a rack adapter which will make it much easier to use in non-ruby based projects.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this question was posed quite a while ago, but in case someone else lands here in search of the same info...

Here's a good one:
http://adityabhandari.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ColorChanger.html

It allows you to shift the hue for the whole color scheme, though unfortunately it doesn't have lightness/darkness and saturation capabilities.

Comment: That URL is not available any more. Please remove.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally this tool may work also: http://css-color-replace.orca-multimedia.de/

It is pretty much close to what 
http://cssprism.com/
can do